# nginx gives 500 while deploying through chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra, recipe

I am trying to deploy rails app through chef . I have written a recipe using deploy resource and it deploys without any issues .

```
deploy "master" do   
  repo "#{node['git']['repo']}"  
  action :deploy   
  branch 'master'  

  before_migrate do 
    current_release_directory = release_path
    running_deploy_user = "#{node['user']}"
    bundler_depot = new_resource.shared_path + '/bundle'

    script 'Bundling' do
      interpreter 'bash'
      cwd current_release_directory
      user running_deploy_user
      code <<-EOS
        bundle install --quiet  --path #{bundler_depot} \         
      EOS
    end

    script 'Migrating data' do
      interpreter 'bash'
      cwd current_release_directory
      user running_deploy_user
      code <<-EOS
        bundle exec rake deploy
      EOS
    end 
  end

  rollback_on_error true;
  deploy_to  "#{node['app']['directory']}"
  environment "RAILS_ENV" => "production"
  scm_provider Chef::Provider::Git
  user "#{node['user']}"
  git_ssh_wrapper   "/tmp/ssh_wrapper.sh"
end
```

When i try to execute again , the nginx gives 500 error , and log says "Cannot stat '/home/ubuntu/apps/current/config.ru; This error means that the Nginx worker process (PID 8094, running as UID 33) does not have permission to access this file" . This issue exists till chef deployment completes . Permissions were unchanged for the directory before and after deployment. How can i get out of this issue ?

Comment: Nothing obvious comes to my mind. What's `node['user']`? What are permissions for `apps/current` and `apps/releases/` directories? Are you using passenger?

Comment: node['user'] is ubuntu and apps directory has permission of  775. Yes using passenger .

Comment: Got it . Its the permission issue. chef used to modify the permission while deploying. Set to +x for the directory . Now its working . Thanks @makhan for the hint .